# What are the most used PHP image manipulation classes?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I am a newbie with php and I want to play with php and images uploaded.

What are the most used PHP image manipulation classes ?

Comment: Hard to tell, as there are no usage statistics. Why not rephrase to ask what image manipulation classes are there - also mentioning what you want to do?

Comment: *(reference)* [Image Processing and Generation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you're just starting I'd suggest taking a look at the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions. They come with PHP (assuming you have GD enabled).

If you need more power then there's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), but you have to install it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Most used is hard to find but a large list of php classes can be found here:

http://phpclasses.fonant.com/browse/class/11.html

You can do alot with the built in GD graphics library:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1):

I am building an easy to use OO image manipulation library with intuitive API. Its publicly available on GitHub - https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine